# how to include javascript files in Google Gears Worker (no DOM access)

Tags: javascript, gears, worker, include-guards

how does one include other .js files in the .js of a Worker. Every "include" solution for Javascript that I've found does it by loading into a  tag, which is not an option for Workers since they don't have access to the DOM.

I see from your [950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) that using Ajax and `eval()` will do it. I can figure that out but please point me to reference implementation if there's an easy one.

Someone proposed WorkerPool.load() back in 2007 here http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/NewWorkerPoolFeatures?redir=1  . Was anything like that ever done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution: http://sviudes.blogspot.com/2009/09/simular-un-include-en-un-worker-de.html

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Workers (as supported by Safari 4 and Firefox 3.5) has the importScripts function -- presumably Gears also supports it.